# Why won't an anchor tag generated with JQuery fire its onclick event?

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically generating an anchor tag using jQuery. I have added an onclick attribute to it but when I click on the link the onclick does not fire.

I am generating the link as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var attributes = {
        "id": "xxx",
        "onclick": "alert('xxxx');",
        "href": "https://localhost/widget/TabTest.aspx#"
    };
    var link = $.create("a", attributes);
    $(link).append("xxxx");
    $("#WidgetContainer").append(link);
});
```

Comment: Worth noting that $.create isn't part of jQuery proper. I thought I just wasn't familiar with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the click attribute with the jQuery's click() function.

```
var attributes = {
     "id": "xxx",
     "href": "https://localhost/widget/TabTest.aspx#"
 };
 var link = $.create("a", attributes);
 $(link).append("xxxx").click(function(){ alert("HELLO"); });
 $("#WidgetContainer").append(link);
```

What you did will likely work in some browsers but not others (I'd had that work in FF but fail in IE). Generally, if jQuery has a function to do something, use it.

---

EDIT:
In response to Adam Backstrom's comment on the question I figured I'd better offer an alternative.  When I've done this in the past, I did it like this:

```
$("#someplace").wrapInner("<a href='#'></a>");
$("#someplace a").click(function() {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

---

EDIT 2:
From the comments to this post, how to do this in one line (not always in the best idea):

```
$("<a id='xxx' href='https://localhost/widget/TabTest.aspx#'>xxxx</a>")
      .click(function() { alert("Hello"); })
      .appendTo($("#WidgetContainer"));
```

Comment: Long live the overly-terse jQuery; there is almost always a way to write it entirely on one line (whether you should or not):
$("<a id='xxx' href='https://localhost/widget/TabTest.aspx#'>xxxx</a>").click(function() { alert("Hello"); }).appendTo($("#WidgetContainer"));

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery 1.3 or above, you could use "live" event binding to attach the click event to any <A> tags you add to your page. E.g.:

```
$('a').live('click', function (evt) {
    alert('Hello');
    evt.preventDefault();
});
var link = $.create('a', {
    'id' : 'xxx',
    'href' : 'http://localhost/'
});
$('#container').append(link);
```